# Tooltip does not appear for the overlapped circles in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am creating a scatter Plot in which the points sometimes overlap each other. On mouse-over on any of those points, either the tooltip flickers or sometimes it does not appear. Can any one help me out with this?

```
dots.on("mouseenter", function(d) {
                d3.select(this).attr({
                    r: radius * 2
                });
                d3.selectAll(".crosshair")
                    .style("display", "block");

                var xCoord = d3.mouse(this)[0];
                var yCoord = d3.mouse(this)[1];

                addCrossHair(xCoord, yCoord);
                tooltipDiv
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 2) + "px")
                    .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 28) + "px")
                    .style("opacity", 0.9)
                    .style("display", "block")
                    .html(content);
            });

            dots.on("mouseout", function(d) {

                d3.select(this).attr({
                    r: radius
                });
                d3.selectAll(".crosshair")
                    .style("display", "none");

                tooltipDiv.transition()
                   .duration(100)       
                   .style("display", "none");
            });

        //tooltip //
        var tooltipDiv = d3.select("#scatterChart")
                    .append("div")
                        .attr("class", "d3-tip n")
                        .style("opacity", 0)
                        .style("position","fixed")
                        .style("display", "block")
                        .style("top", 100)
                        .style("left", 100)
                        .style("pointer-events","none");

        //crossHair//               
         function addCrossHair(xCoord, yCoord) {
            if(!xCoord || !yCoord){ // don't draw cross hair if no valid coordinates given
                return;
            }
            d3.select("#h_crosshair")
                .attr("x1", 0)
                .attr("y1", yCoord)
                .attr("x2", width)
                .attr("y2", yCoord)
                .style("display", "block");

            d3.select("#v_crosshair")
                .attr("x1", xCoord)
                .attr("y1", 0)
                .attr("x2", xCoord)
                .attr("y2", height)
                .style("display", "block");
        }
```

[image: On mouseover on the overlapped circles the tooltip does not appear]

Comment: Please add a [mcve] demonstrating the issue you're facing to the question.

Comment: Although your efforts to include a *minimal* example are acknoledged. it is neither *complete* nor *verifiable*. Please read the resource linked to in Robert Longson's comment. It will be much easier to help you out if there is something actually demonstrating the effect and to fiddle around with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution for the above question asked by me.
On mouse-out the duration given to the tooltip was causing the flickering issue.

```
       dots.on("mouseout", function(d) {

            d3.select(this).attr({
                r: radius
            });
            d3.selectAll(".crosshair")
                .style("display", "none");

            tooltipDiv.transition()      
               .style("display", "none");
        });
```

On removing the duration(100), the above raised issue was solved.